# How does the global variable behave inside function(Python)

Tags: python, variables, scope

Case 1

```
A = '213'
def wow():
    print(A)
wow()
Output: '213'
```

Case 2

```
A = '213'
def wow():
    print(A)
    A = 12
wow()
Output: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'A' referenced before assignment
```

I'd thought that the output in the case 2 would be identical to the case 1, since A is a global variable and I called "print(A)" *before* reassigning value to A within the function. So my question is, why in the case 1 calling A is  perfectly fine, but case 2 throws error?

Answer (score 1):

Because you are modifying it, so you would need `global`:

```
A = '213'
def wow():
    global A
    print(A)
    A = 12
wow()
```

`global` allows you to modify it too.

Comment: @Tomerikoo Oh yeah didn't see that, should i delete this